# How to update an Adaptive Card in Teams after an event happened on another platform?

Tags: c#, bots, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am trying to make a bot that sends a notification in Teams to a manager when someone ask for an approval from my online software. The manager receives an adaptive card with the possibility to approve or refuse in Teams and when he submits I send the data to my app. That I achieved.

The problem happens when I try to update my card so that it stays up to date. It is "easy" to refresh it when the manager clicks on one of the buttons in my Adaptive Card but I would also like to update/refresh my card if the manager accepts or refuses the request directly on my online app.

**Is there some way to trigger the refresh of a an adaptive card from an HTTP call with new data / an external event ?**

Thanks in advance for your help I've been looking online for days and didn't find anything (documentation/posts/samples/...) regarding this subject.

If it helps, I am making my bot using C#.

Comment: In order to sync the user's progress across devices, use the refresh property in Adaptive Card JSON. Could you please refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/universal-actions-for-adaptive-cards/sequential-workflows) and let us know if it helps?